# Can I run different versions of my website based on detection of mode

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

I would like to create one website. This website will have behave differently if I am viewing it at a specific event via a kiosk. The kiosk, will just be an iPad. I believe I can figure out how to lock down the iPad to act like a kiosk and just show my website based on this http://www.webascender.com/Blog/ID/447/How-to-Setup-Kiosk-Mode-Lock-Your-iPad-to-Just-One-App#.U9Fx3oBdVX4

But what I am asking is, in code, is there a way to detect that I am in 'kiosk' mode and show different pages? For example, if you are at home(or anywhere that is NOT the event) you should be able to hit my website to find out all about my company and to view your existing profile. You should be able to see these same pages on the 'kiosk'(the iPad while at an event) but you will now see additional pages such as pages dealing with the specific event and payment pages. Vice-versa you might be able to see additional pages on the website while at home that you will not see while in 'kiosk' mode.

I do not know if the solution is tools/language dependent as we have not settled yet on all tools/languages/frameworks we will be using to build the site and so I am open to all but we will definitely have some javascript/css/html.

Comment: I know you can do this in a native app using the `UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled` method, but since this is a _website_, I don't think it's possible to detect being as this mode is software enabled and outside the scope of the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will need to write a native app in order to detect whether you are in 'guided access' aka 'kiosk' mode.

Taken from [Detect or react to Guided Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663481/detect-or-react-to-guided-access)

```
NSLog(@"Accessabilitiy enabled: %@", UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled() ? @"YES" : @"NO");

if (!UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled()) {
   // show something since I'm not in guided access
}
```

If you want to know when it changes...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(guidedAccessChanged) name:UIAccessibilityGuidedAccessStatusDidChangeNotification object:nil];

- (void)guidedAccessChanged
{
    // do something when guided access changes
}
```

If you must work with a website then what you can do is write a native app that embeds a [`UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This class allows you to show websites within a native app. So, what you could do with this method is pass along the guided access setting to your website so that it can adjust itself accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the IP address you can direct views using PHP (and probably a host of other programs).  Or you can lock the iPad to only open a specific URL `(http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com)` and only have pages that you want viewed by the kiosk.  I'm sure there are a mess of other ways too.